# How to display broken Japanese text correctly when Dompdf is used?

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, cjk, font-family, magento2.4

I am trying to export PDF file by using Dompdf.
Here, html code is converted to PDF.
PDF file export is working correctly.
日文字体Rounded Mgen  1p light.ttf file exist in 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/libs/fonts' .

```
public function getPrintHtml($data){
            $html = '
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                            <style type="text/css">
                                @font-face {
                                    font-family: \'Meiryo\';
                                    font-style: normal;
                                    font-weight: 400;
                                    src: url(dompdf/fonts/日文字体Rounded Mgen  1p light.ttf) format(\'truetype\'); 
                                }
                                body {
                                    font-family: Meiryo;
                                }
                            </style>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <div class="main-content" style="width: 1200px; margin: 10px auto;">
                                <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <h2>修理パック受理書兼回数券</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="font-size:13px;">
                                    <p style="margin:0px">この度は弊社でのご購入誠にありがとうございます。お客様の修理パックの受理が完了致しました。</p>
                                    <p style="margin:0px">下記の回数券をご使用まで大事に保管ください。回数券の再発行はできません。</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                    <table style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width:50%;border: 4px dotted darkgrey;padding: 10px;">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">1回目</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">'.$data["warranty_number"].'</span>
                                                        <span style="float:right;font-size:12px;">株式会社ウヱダ</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                                        <p style="font-size:18px"><b>電動工具修理保証回数券</b></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <p style="font-size:10px">修理保証期間はご購入日よりパックに応じた1～3年間または修理お預り回数1～3回以内になります。修理依頼時の送料はお客様ご負担になります。修理保証は上記番号にてご登録頂いております下記商品に限ります。※バッテリー充電器は修理不可商品の為対象外です。</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">パック種類：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">2年保証</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">メーカー名：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["maker"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">商品名：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["product_name"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">JANコード：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["jan_code"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">製造番号：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["serial_number"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">名前：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["firstname"].' '.$data["lastname"].'('.$data["firstname_gana"].' '.$data["lastname_gana"].')'.'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;padding-bottom:3px;">
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">（購入日）</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px;color:red"><b>'.$data["purchase_at"].'</b></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width:50%;border: 4px dotted darkgrey;padding: 10px;">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">2回目</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">'.$data["warranty_number"].'</span>
                                                        <span style="float:right;font-size:12px;">株式会社ウヱダ</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                                        <p style="font-size:18px"><b>電動工具修理保証回数券</b></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <p style="font-size:10px">修理保証期間はご購入日よりパックに応じた1～3年間または修理お預り回数1～3回以内になります。修理依頼時の送料はお客様ご負担になります。修理保証は上記番号にてご登録頂いております下記商品に限ります。※バッテリー充電器は修理不可商品の為対象外です。</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">パック種類：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">2年保証</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">メーカー名：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["maker"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">商品名：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["product_name"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">JANコード：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["jan_code"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">製造番号：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["serial_number"].'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">名前：</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:10px">'.$data["firstname"].' '.$data["lastname"].'('.$data["firstname_gana"].' '.$data["lastname_gana"].')'.'</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;padding-bottom:3px;">
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px">（購入日）</span>
                                                        <span style="font-size:12px;color:red"><b>'.$data["purchase_at"].'</b></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="width: 100%;float: left;">
                                    <h3 style="margin:5px 0px">受理後の返信書類をお持ちの方のみが対象となります。本紙の回数券をお持ちでない場合は本サービスをお受けすることができませんので厳重に保管ください。修理ご希望の場合はご一報ください。</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="float: left;">
                                    <p style="margin:0px"><b>≪修理保証について≫</b></p>
                                    <ul style="margin:0px">
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">購入後、2週間以内に番号の登録がなかった場合、ご連絡いただいた製造番号が実機と異なっていた場合、製造番号に誤りがあった場合、写真登録前に使用していた場合、修理保証の対象外・修理保証取消になることがありますのでご了承ください。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">修理保証パックは受理後の受理書兼回数券をお持ちのお客様が対象となります。回数券の再発行可能期間は最長1週間とさせていただきます。後日の再発行ができませんので返送させていただきます受理書兼回数券は大切に保管ください。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">修理をお出しいただく際に弊社へ必ず連絡を頂き、回数券を始めにご提示いただきましたお客様のみ回数券の使用が有効です。修理後のご提示、他社での修理請求に対してはご使用できません。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">メーカーの保証と弊社修理保証パックの保証範囲は異なります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">弊社の修理保証対象は通常ご使用時の自然故障を前提としております。お預かり時に落下・分解・水濡れ、故障ではなく外傷破損などの過失がみられる場合、またお預かり後メーカー判断により過失が判断された場合は有償となります。修理代金にご了承頂けない場合は、修理保証パック代金を返金させて頂きます。例)許容範囲外の使用がみられた場合、モーター焼けの場合、人災・自然災害での故障の場合など。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">本契約はご購入のお客様とのご契約になりますので第三者のご利用に伴う故障・保証については対応できかねます。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">レーザー・オートレベル・ローティングレーザーなどの精密機器につきましては現物を確認させていただき、転倒症状がみられる場合は、保証の対象外になります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">タジマ・KDSのレーザー墨出し器の修理を、弊社を通さず直接ご依頼された場合は対象外となります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">故障原因、使用状態等の確認ができない場合は保証の対象外となる場合がございます。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">規定に基づいた内容の保証の為、期限内であっても有償になる場合がございます。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">当保証につきましては適用する故障内容に対する保証の為、精度調整を含む点検等のお受けは承っておりません。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">1回目の修理完成品返送時送料は弊社にて負担させていただきます。※2回目以降の返送時の送料はお客様ご負担になります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">ご購入時に付属のバッテリー・充電器の故障・消耗品等の交換は保証対象外となります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">モニターの破損など液晶画面は保証対象外となります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">弊社で販売しております商品はすべて国内使用を目的としたお客様へ販売させて頂いております。国外での使用、持ち出しが確認できました時点で保証は取消となります。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">防犯登録は、製造番号登録ですので盗難や紛失による損害は負いかねます。保証対象商品への偽りや、書類コピー、転売などのルールに反する行為が発覚次第、一切のサービスを受けられないものとします。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">万が一、期限内に登録されなかった場合や、保証をお使いになられない場合の返金は一切お受けしておりません。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">ご購入後の修理保証パックのお申込みは、原則としてお受付できません 但し例外としてご相談頂きました内容によっては、商品発送後3日以内に限り、弊社で判断させて頂いた上でお受けさせて頂く場合もございます。（※1年タイプに限ります）</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">ご注文後にメーカーの価格改定が発覚した場合、修理保証パックをお受付できない場合がございます。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">商品発送後の修理パックの内容変更はお受付できません。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">原則としてお客様からの契約解除はお受けできませんが、契約内容に沿わないと添わないと弊社で判断させていただきましたお客様につきましては、弊社から契約解除をさせて頂く場合もございますのでご了承ください</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">本規約は随時更新され、最新の規約の内容が適応されます。</li>
                                      <li style="font-size:12px;">お申し込みは上記全てをご理解いただいたものといたします。</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>';
            return $html;
        }
```

File export part as follow.

```
public function generatePDF($html,$id){
            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
            $dompdf->load_html($html, 'UTF-8');
            $dompdf->set_option('default_charset', 'utf8');
            $dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Meiryo'); // Set a font that supports Japanese characters
            $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->set_option('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->set_option('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->set_option('isJavascriptEnabled', true);
            $dompdf->setPaper('A2', 'portrait');
            $dompdf->render();
            $output = $dompdf->output();
            $mediaPath = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::class)->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $pdfFile = file_put_contents($mediaPath . "/Uedakanamono/netprint/".$id."_card.pdf", $output);
            return $id."_card.pdf";
        }
```

The result of PDF file export is as follow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXeMd.png)

How to display it correctly? Please post example code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues? It's looks to still be actively maintained, so if you're following their instructions and you get this, they _probably_ want to know about that so they can fix things.